# Let user push a git repo to me, then I save it to a directory in my webserver

Tags: git, github

I want to let a user create a repo, then push it to my web application.  When it's "pushed" to my application, I will take the files and copy them into a directory on my server.

The goal here is to let people push me small applications which I can then serve. Ideally they could run something as simple as `git push donnys_site master` and my site would start delivering their application (very similar to heroku's workflow).

What should I be researching for this?

Below is the best method I've thought of:

```
1. User creates a git repo.
2. User adds `donnys_site` as a remote.
3. User does `$ git push donny_site master`. 
4. My site receives the push... not sure what this really entails. Maybe I need my own git repo for each repo being pushed to me? 
5. I believe git has post-commit hooks, which let me take action. So use a post-commit hook to trigger a script to copy their files to a directory thats acting as a webserver.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should work.

On the server site you need a bare repository for others to push to.
You can configure a hook on that repository that is triggered whenever someone pushes to the repository. Have a look at `git help githooks` for details. Maybe an update hook would be good in your case.

The hook itself can be a bash script or any other executable. You can check out the newly pushed data and write it wherever your site requires it.